# Unknown table when building ADO.NET Data entity in MySQL

Tags: mysql, ado.net

I cannot generate a MySQL data model using Visual Studio with ADO.NET data entity because I get this error:

> An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details.
>       Unknown table 'parameters' in information_schema

I downloaded the .NET Connector 6.3.6.

How can this be solved?

Answer (score 2):

Answer is here: [MySQL Bugs #61793 'Unknown table 'PARAMETERS' in information_schema'](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=61793)

Apparently it's because: "Connector/NET is trying to read the stored procedure parameters from `parameters` table in Information_Schema database. This table exists in MySQL 5.5 or newer."